# "Readable Stream has ended before it was serialized" in npm/jsonstreamstringify

Tags: javascript, stream

I have a worker that generates data like this:

```js
for (const item in queue){
    const data = await get_data();
    data_stream.push(data);
}
```

There may be multiple of these workers running simultaneously, and they all push to the same stream.
This `stream` is `Readable` and is fed to a `JsonStreamStringify` like this:

```js
data_stream = new stream.Readable({ objectMode: true, read() { } })
new JsonStreamStringify({foo: data_stream, ...other stuff}).pipe(some file writing stream);
```

When all the workers have finished, we end the stream with

```js
data_stream.push(null)
```

But I get this error:

```js
(node:17) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Readable Stream has ended before it was serialized. All stream data have been lost
    at JsonStreamStringify.addToStack (/usr/src/app/node_modules/json-stream-stringify/umd.js:316:32)
    at JsonStreamStringify.processObject (/usr/src/app/node_modules/json-stream-stringify/umd.js:404:14)
    at JsonStreamStringify.processStackTopItem (/usr/src/app/node_modules/json-stream-stringify/umd.js:506:53)
    at JsonStreamStringify.__read (/usr/src/app/node_modules/json-stream-stringify/umd.js:532:21)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/json-stream-stringify/umd.js:539:22)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

Which has zero results on Google and doesn't give me a useful line number to track the bug down.

Any ideas why this error is being thrown?  Or a better solution for passing data from my workers to the `JsonStreamStringify` object?

## Desired output

The file that we write to should contain json like

```
{
    foo: {
        [data1, data2, ...]
    }
}
```

When the program crashes, we have json like:

```
{
    foo: {
        [
```